# Do I need to clean the objects in the deque in the destructor?

Tags: c++, deque

my deque contains object, NOT pointer.

such as:

```
class MyObject                // no pointer inside the object, all simple type/prmitive
{
  string name;
  string value;
}

MyObject object1, object2;
m_deq.push_back(object1); 
m_deq.push_back(object2);
```

I know if it's pointer, I have to clean it in desconstructor.

My question is: if just object, Is it true that I don't have to clean MyObject like:

```
for ( unsigned int i = 0 ; i < m_deq.size(); i++ )
{
    delete &m_deq[i];
}
```

Comment: Did you have to delete the pointers when you stored pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you do not have to clear the `std::deque` if you only stored value objects in there. The `std::deque` destructor will call the destructor for each object it contains.